# Removing eventHandler in function called by addEventListener

Tags: javascript, reactjs, addeventlistener

I added an infinite scrolling feature to my page. It attaches an event listener in the componentDidMount lifecycle hook and I want to remove it within the action called by the event listener when there is no "nextlink anymore". I set a console.log() message which works fine, but I am uncertain why the window.removeEventListener() function does not work. Any help would be appreciated.

Piece of code responsible for adding/removing the eventListener.

```
componentDidMount() {
    this._isMounted = true;
    this.props.onFetchTeams();

    this.scrollListener = window.addEventListener("scroll", e => {
        this.handleScroll(e);
    });
}

handleScroll = () => {
    const hasMoreLink = this.props.teams["@odata.nextLink"];

    if (hasMoreLink == "") {
        console.log("remove event handler");
        window.removeEventListener("scroll", this.handleScroll);
    }

    // If there is at least a team and is currently not loading, proceed to load more.
    if (this.state.loadingMore === false && this.props.teams["value"]) {
        // get the last teamcard in the page
        const lastTeam = document.querySelector(
            ".team-card-wrapper:last-of-type"
        );

        // get the height of the current team, and get the height of the current position on screen.
        const lastTeamOffset = lastTeam.offsetTop + lastTeam.clientHeight;
        const pageOffset = window.pageYOffset + window.innerHeight;

        // the range that teams will load earlier than the bottom of the page.
        const bottomOffset = 30;

        if (pageOffset > lastTeamOffset - bottomOffset) {
            this.setState({ loadingMore: true });
            this.props.onFetchMoreTeams(hasMoreLink);
        }
    }
};
```

[image]

Comment: What is logged when doing `console.log(hasMoreLink)` ?

Comment: as lon as there is still data to fetch it will log the link to get the next batch of results. from a microsoft api. After that it will return nothing and the console.log(''remove event handler) will execute. I will update my post to add a screenshot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`removeListener` needs the same reference for function that it used while `addListener`. Change the code to addEventListener like

```
this.scrollListener = window.addEventListener("scroll", this.handleScroll);
```

Comment: that worked, thanks. Will accept as accepted answer when allowed.

Answer (score 0):

Consider revising the way your add the scroll event handler, by passing the `handleScroll` function directly:

```
componentDidMount() {
    this._isMounted = true;
    this.props.onFetchTeams();

    /* 
    With the this.handleScroll bound to this class instance, we can now pass the method 
    directly to addEventListener as shown
    */
    this.scrollListener = window.addEventListener("scroll", this.handleScroll);
}

handleScroll = () => {
    const hasMoreLink = this.props.teams["@odata.nextLink"];

    if (hasMoreLink == "") {
        console.log("remove event handler");
        /* This will now work as expected */
        window.removeEventListener("scroll", this.handleScroll);
    }

    /* Rest of your code remains unchanged .. */
}
```

Comment: handleScroll is a ES6 arrow function, doesn't this automatically bind it to the class?
See section 13.1: http://exploringjs.com/es6/ch_arrow-functions.html

Answer (score 0):

This is because the function that is given to addEventListener and the one given to the removeEventListener should be exactly the same, but in your case, you are creating a new arrow function for the addEventListener. so I think you should try something like this:

```
this.scrollListener = window.addEventListener("scroll", this.handleScroll)
...
handleScroll = (e) => {
    ...
    if(noMoreScroll) window.removeEventListener("scroll", this.handleScroll)
    ...
}
```

I hope this helps you :)